# CXF Web service client error

Tags: cxf

I am trying to invoke a web service  from java client using apache CXF. Following is my client code snippet.

```
Client client = new ClientImpl(new URL("http://localhost:8080/socialkast-web/services/skservice?wsdl"));
Object[] results = client.invoke("uploadVideoMetaData", new Object[] {metaData});
  String result = (String)results[0];
```

I am getting parsing error although i am able to access the wsdl file from browser. Following is the exception stack.

```
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14f5a31: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationListener,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister#0,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver,org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.javascript.JavascriptQueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.transport.local.LocalTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ClientOnlyHTTPTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.object.ObjectBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.http.HttpBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.DomainExpressionBuilderRegistry,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.EndpointReferenceDomainExpressionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMManager,org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.policy.RMPolicyInterceptorProvider,org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.RMAssertionBuilder,org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.wsdl.WSDLExtensionRegister#1]; root of factory hierarchy
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:69)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.<init>(ClientImpl.java:152)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.<init>(ClientImpl.java:121)
 at tv.socialkast.client.ws.WSClient.<init>(WSClient.java:42)
 at tv.socialkast.upload.client.gui.UploadDirectoryChooser$DoneActionListener.actionPerformed(UploadDirectoryChooser.java:382)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
**Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:8080/socialkast-web/services/skservice?wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**
 at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:232)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:161)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:67)
 ... 29 more
```

Please advice what am I missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This could be something really obvious, but have you tried hitting your service from your browser? For example, try getting wsdl by pointing your web browser to:

```
http://localhost:8080/socialkast-web/services/skservice?wsdl
```

If you can't get there, maybe your server isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough: Your server isn't responding.

```
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:8080/socialkast-web/services/skservice?wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source
```

Comment: Please note when I access the same wsdl url(http://localhost:8080/socialkast-web/services/skservice?wsdl) from browser, I get the correct wsdl file displayed in browser.

Comment: Could you have perhaps neglected to put the HTTP transport in the classpath? I recommend posting a JIRA with a test case at cxf.apache.org, it would be easier to help you there.

Comment: sure I'll post a jira. Could you elaborate steps about putting HTTP transport in the classpath.

Comment: you don't have the right error message for me to be confident, but... talking over HTTP is the job of a specific CXF jar (cxf-rt-transports-http). Depending on how you put CXF in your classpath, it could be missing. Mostly, I'm stumped that you could get the error you got and have it work to retrieve in the browser.

Comment: I am using maven to build the project. I added the "cxf-rt-transports-http" in pom.xml but still same problem. BTW I have sent you the entire exception stack. Even I am wondering why I am not able to access the wsdl from my application when it is accessible from browser.

Comment: The entire stack amounts to, "cxf tried to connect to the server and got a connection refused". users@cxf.apache.org works better for support, this is clearly not a simple question with an answer.

Comment: I tried asking in users@cxf.apache.org but no answer till date. I believe it is not an issue with CXF. It looks like it is something related to my machine setting which is blocking my soap calls to the server. Do you know or ever face such issue with the machine networking settings. I am using Windows Vista.

Comment: Really? Can you link me to the archive at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/?

Comment: please look at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201012.mbox/%3C1293828276953-3323904.post@n5.nabble.com%3E