# Webservice Client program unable to call service

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have written a sample CXF webservice program and deployed using,Apache in local machine.

This is my WSDL URL :

```
http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService/SubWS?wsdl
```

And I am able to access it.

But when I am trying to run the client program it is throwing error -->

---

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:97)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.service.substract.subwsdlfile.SubWSDLFile_Service.<init>(SubWSDLFile_Service.java:43)
    at com.service.substract.subwsdlfile.SubWSDLFile_SubWSDLFileSOAP_Client.main(SubWSDLFile_SubWSDLFileSOAP_Client.java:53)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService/SubWS?wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService/SubWS?wsdl
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService/SubWS?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Client code

```
package com.service.substract.subwsdlfile;

/**
 * Please modify this class to meet your needs
 * This class is not complete
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.6.1
 * 2012-12-09T17:44:09.725+05:30
 * Generated source version: 2.6.1
 * 
 */
public final class SubWSDLFile_SubWSDLFileSOAP_Client {

    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://substract.service.com/SubWSDLFile/", "SubWSDLFile");

    private SubWSDLFile_SubWSDLFileSOAP_Client() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
        URL wsdlURL = SubWSDLFile_Service.WSDL_LOCATION;
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) { 
            File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
            try {
                if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                    wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
                } else {
                    wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SubWSDLFile_Service ss = new SubWSDLFile_Service(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        SubWSDLFile port = ss.getSubWSDLFileSOAP();  

        {
        System.out.println("Invoking substractOp...");
        com.service.substract.substractwsschema.SubsbtractRequest _substractOp_substractRequest = new com.service.substract.substractwsschema.SubsbtractRequest();
        _substractOp_substractRequest.setParam1(-735195532);
        _substractOp_substractRequest.setParam2(633197322);
        com.service.substract.substractwsschema.SubstractResponse _substractOp__return = port.substractOp(_substractOp_substractRequest);
        System.out.println("substractOp.result=" + _substractOp__return);


        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

}


package com.service.substract.subwsdlfile;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.6.1
 * 2012-12-09T17:44:09.805+05:30
 * Generated source version: 2.6.1
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "SubWSDLFile", 
                  wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService?wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://substract.service.com/SubWSDLFile/") 
public class SubWSDLFile_Service extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://substract.service.com/SubWSDLFile/", "SubWSDLFile");
    public final static QName SubWSDLFileSOAP = new QName("http://substract.service.com/SubWSDLFile/", "SubWSDLFileSOAP");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
           //url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService?wsdl");
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SubWSDLFile_Service.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService?wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public SubWSDLFile_Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public SubWSDLFile_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public SubWSDLFile_Service() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }


    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns SubWSDLFile
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SubWSDLFileSOAP")
    public SubWSDLFile getSubWSDLFileSOAP() {
        return super.getPort(SubWSDLFileSOAP, SubWSDLFile.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns SubWSDLFile
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SubWSDLFileSOAP")
    public SubWSDLFile getSubWSDLFileSOAP(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(SubWSDLFileSOAP, SubWSDLFile.class, features);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try calling `http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService/SubWS` instead (without `wsdl` suffix).

Comment: Add your client code. Can you access the wsdl url from a browser? Can you execute the webservice using Soap UI.

Comment: Tomasz : I have tried as you said, but that is also not working.

Comment: @gkamal : Yes I am able to access wsdl at this URL http://localhost:8080/SubstractWebService/SubWS?wsdl

I have added the client code in the question.

Comment: It could be because of proxy - your client is not able to make the http call.  You could add some code to see if you can access this url from within your java code. Or try the proxy properties as discussed in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493875/cxf-web-service-client-error

Comment: @gkamal Definitely my eclipse is not able to make HTTP connection. But what can be the reason for that. Any Eclipse configurations?

Comment: Do you use proxies to connect to the network?

Comment: you can also try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost